# laravel change login/logout redirection to home

Tags: laravel, authentication

When installing the Auth package on Laravel (5.3), a new, unnnamed route is created :

```
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
```

Problem is, I'd want them to be redirected to the root of my website.

For the moment, I update the index method on HomeController to make the redirection, but I'm sure there is a better way to tell the Auth package to redirect to another page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override the default redirection by changing the `$redirectTo` variable in your login and registration controllers.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the similar problem here.
I did already override the default redirection paths to '/' in all auth controllers.

But after logging in, visiting the "/login" page again keeps me redirecting to "/home". Is there anything else i need to do?